# Raven DB: How is 'smuggler' different from 'Import/Export'?

Tags: backup, ravendb

With Raven DB, there is a program called "Smuggler" which allows dumps to be taken of Raven DB. However, there is also an option within Raven DB Management Studio to 'Import/Export' database.

What is the difference?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no difference, Import/Export uses the same code as smuggler

Comment: Any idea why using the UI Import/Export goes faster than Smuggler?

Comment: @Ayende this is an old answer but is it still vaild? I hit a wall attempting to export data from my dev env into production. This topic suggests that Sumggler is a work around: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9047428/1944699