# RavenDB Error: Version of log file is not compatible with Jet version

Tags: ravendb, windows-2003-webserver

So I installed RavendDB on a Win2003 server using these instructions:

http://old.ravendb.net/documentation/docs-deployment-iis

And i get the following error when I try to browse to the site. Any ideas?

```
Version of log file is not compatible with Jet version 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.EsentBadLogVersionException: Version of log file is not compatible with Jet version

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[EsentBadLogVersionException: Version of log file is not compatible with Jet version]
   Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.Api.Check(Int32 err) in C:\Work\ravendb\SharedLibs\Sources\managedesent-61618\EsentInterop\Api.cs:2739
   Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.Api.JetInit(JET_INSTANCE& instance) in C:\Work\ravendb\SharedLibs\Sources\managedesent-61618\EsentInterop\Api.cs:131
   Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.Initialize(IUuidGenerator uuidGenerator) in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Storage.Esent\TransactionalStorage.cs:207

[InvalidOperationException: Could not open transactional storage: C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\RavenDB\Data\Data]
   Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.Initialize(IUuidGenerator uuidGenerator) in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Storage.Esent\TransactionalStorage.cs:220
   Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase..ctor(InMemoryRavenConfiguration configuration) in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Database\DocumentDatabase.cs:151
   Raven.Web.ForwardToRavenRespondersFactory.Init() in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Web\ForwardToRavenRespondersFactory.cs:62
   Raven.Web.RavenDbStartupAndShutdownModule.<Init>b__0(Object sender, EventArgs args) in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Web\BootStrapper.cs:12
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +213
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +76
```

Comment: Did you run RavenDB on a different OS and then transfer it to Windows Server 2003? Or have you only run it under 2003?

Comment: I transferred from my win7 desktop. Do I have to start from scratch? How do I transfer the DBs that I have created?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The RavenDB datastore uses [Esent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Storage_Engine) under the hood. As a result it's not portable across OS versions. I.e. if you create a store on one version of an OS, it won't necessarily work on another just by copying the files across.

You can use the [RavenDB smuggler](http://ravendb.net/docs/server/administration/export-import) tool to import/export the data. Or do it manually.

Comment: @legion if this answer worked for you would you consider marking it as the accepted answer? That way it helps anyone else looking at the question.